# Register to listen when a notification was accepted or rejected

Tags: android, react-native

In my app I have set up periodic notification using [react-native-push-notification](https://github.com/zo0r/react-native-push-notification). I have registered to listen to when the notification was accepted or rejected in the `componentWillMount`  method in the App.js file

> ```
> PushNotificationAndroid.registerNotificationActions(['Accept','Reject','Yes','No']);
>   DeviceEventEmitter.addListener('notificationActionReceived', function(action){
>     Alert.alert('Notification action received: ' + action);
>   });
> ```

I get notifications periodically, but the listener is not firing. What I am doing wrong?